# Insert comma between Anchor widgets

Tags: java, gwt

I have this template and code below to generate a "tags" in my web application as inidicated in the sample output:

**Template:**

```
<p class="tag" data-field="tags">Tags:
</p>
```

**Java code:**

```
@DataField
DivElement tags = DOM.createElement("p").cast();

@Override
public void setModel(MyModel model) {
   binder.setModel(model, InitialState.FROM_MODEL);
   for (String tag : model.getTags()){
       Anchor a = new Anchor();
       a.setText(tag);
       a.setHref("#Tags?id=" + tag);
       tags.appendChild(a.getElement());
       Label comma = new Label(",");
       tags.appendChild(comma.getElement());
   }
}
```

**HTML Output (Browser):**

```
<p data-field="tags" class="tag">Tags:

<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=test">test</a>
<div class="gwt-Label">,</div>
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=tagg">tagg</a>
<div class="gwt-Label">,</div>
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=new">new</a>
<div class="gwt-Label">,</div>
</p>
```

The problem I face now is that the HTML output when run from the browser should be like this:

```
<p data-field="tags" class="tag">Tags:

<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=test">test</a>,
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=tagg">tagg</a>,
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="#Tags?id=new">new</a>
</p>
```

And not create `gwt-label` DIV in between

Comment: @tech-idiot If div tag is present all tags will be in new line, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Label comma = new Label(",");
tags.appendChild(comma.getElement());
```

Use

```
tags.setInnerHTML(tags.getInnerHTML() + ",");
```

Comment: This worked, only that the last tag did have a "," comma also

Answer (score 0):

instead of append child try

```
tags.appendData(",");
```

Comment: There is no method as appendData in Element class.

Comment: oh i was thinking of character data fpasmh!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use SafeHTML. [SafeHTML templates](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/client/SafeHtmlTemplates.html) could also make your code simplier.

```
public interface MyTemplate extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
    @Template("<a class=\"gwt-Anchor\" href=\"#Tags?id={0}\">{1}</a>{2}")
    SafeHtml getTag(String url, String text, String comma);
}
```

(the last argument, "comma" can either be ", " or "").